# Как убрать ненужные символы из вставляемого текста в textarea?

Tags: javascript

Есть скрипт на запрет ввода определенных символов, он прекрасно работает, но если пользователь не наберет текст, а вставит, то заменяется только часть символов. А как сделать, что бы из всего вставленного текста убирались "непотребные" символы?

```html
<p>Проверочный текст: "Это проверочный текст" созданный 23/05/2018г. в 12:00?</p>
<textarea onkeyup="validate(this)" rows="5"> </textarea>
<script>
          function validate(input) {
            input.value = input.value.replace(/[\/\|\\?:<>"]/, "");
        }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нужно добавить флаг [g](https://learn.javascript.ru/regexp-methods#str-replace-reg-str-func), чтобы заменялись все совпадения, а не только первое.

```js
function validate(input) {
  input.value = input.value.replace(/[\/\|\\?:<>"]/g, "");
}
```

```html
<p>Проверочный текст: "Это проверочный текст" созданный 23/05/2018г. в 12:00?</p>
<textarea onkeyup="validate(this)" rows="5"> </textarea>
```

Comment: Супер, спасибо!

Comment: Может быть еще указать, что события `keyup` недостаточно для валидации.